# How to migrate from Oracle RDB for OpenVMS to MySQL in Windows?

Tags: mysql, migration, rdbms, openvms

I have a legacy Alpha server with a [RDBMS database](http://www3.sympatico.ca/n.rieck/docs/openvms%5Fnotes%5Frms%5Frdb.html#rdb). This db is replicated in a MySQL db with many bad php scripts that drops all the tables and takes everything from the Alpha.

This works very slow and is becoming unmaintainable. Is there a better way to fix this than programming again the scripts? Anything like MySQL Migration Toolkit?

Answer (score 1):

I think  the Java SQuirreL  JDBC client has a 3rd party "DBCopy" plugin that allows DB replication through JDBC.  Just a thought.